# Apache not redirecting correctly http to https

Tags: apache, https, virtualhost

I have server with a couple of websites on it. One of the sites (example.com) has to be moved to https.

Opening https://example.com is OK.
But opening http://example.com redirects me to the default virtual host on the server (Let's say http://site1.com). I want to be http://example.com to be redirected to https://example.com.

The configuration is as follows

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  Redirect permanent / https://example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com 
    DocumentRoot /websites/example.com/www
    <Directory /websites/example.com/www>
            DirectoryIndex index.php
    </Directory>

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile .../cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile ..../privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile .../chain.pem

    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

</VirtualHost>
```

It seems like apache doesn't even load the non-secure virtual host

Comment: Which version of Apache you have installed on the server? Do you have `NameVirtualHost *:80` directive in the configuration?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. The apache version  is 2.2.22. I have NameVirtualHost *:80 in ports.conf file. I added in the non-secure VirtualHost ServerAlias www.example.com and it worked. But now it redirects to https://WWW.example.com, not to https://example.com. I'll be happy if someone can explain why it works with the directive ServerAlias.